# Issue with Android Studio after update and old project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm here to write about an issue that I've tried to fix.

I think I was updated a tool in the SDK within Android Studio (not sure which one).After this, I saw a lot of different issues that caused all my old projects to stop working. I uninstalled it and deleted all my data of installations SDK NDK... and reinstalled it, but I see the same error.

When I create a new Android Studio project it's working fine.

If you can help me to solve this issue please.

```
ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\safin\Desktop\Project\projectname 02-05-2018\projectname\projectname\projectname\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[34,9]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
```

[image]

Comment: Create a [mcve] - and don't add screenshots of code or errors.

Answer (score 0):

click on "app" word in that shown console and fix the start or end tag

Comment: Yes, that's take me to the same page build.gradle with out indication of the line exact that i have to correct, i control all detail with new project it's no different changed.

Comment: I cannot know the problem because you don't post the code causing of it! , I just followed your app log message error, please put the code